# How to save a adjacency matrix with "get.adjacency()" in R, with iGraph and RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, igraph, adjacency-matrix

is it possible to save an adjacency matrix after "get.adjacency()" as an adjacency matrix in R? I tried

```
test <- get.adjacency(network)
```

but I´m getting the error

```
Error in View : cannot coerce class "structure("dgCMatrix", package = "Matrix")" to a data.frame.
```

I´m using RStudio and the package iGraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `sparse=FALSE` in the call to `get.adjacency(...)`

```
g <- graph.full(5)
test <- get.adjacency(g)
class(test)
# [1] "dgCMatrix"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "Matrix"

test <- get.adjacency(g,sparse=FALSE)
class(test)
# [1] "matrix"
```