# Merge two dgCMatrix sparse matrices of different size in R

Tags: r, matrix, merge, sparse-matrix

How can I merge two large (around 500k columns and rows) sparse matrices of formal class `dgCMatrix` with different sizes (both columns and rows wise) in R?

Simplyfied example: I have a full 6x6 matrix

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Now I want to merge a second matrix of different size:

```
3 4 5 6
1 0 1 0 0 
3 0 0 1 0 
4 1 0 0 0
```

The result should be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 0 0 0 1 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 1 0
4 1 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I tried `cbindX` and merge but both didn't work as either:

> only matrices and data.frames can be used

or

> cannot coerce class "*structure("dgCMatrix", package = "Matrix")" to a data.frame.

However, I could not change my matrix to `sparse=FALSE` matrix class as suggested here [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597837/how-to-save-a-adjacency-matrix-with-get-adjacency-in-r-with-igraph-and-rstu) or to a data.frame, as in this case R cannot handle the matrix size on my machine anymore.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One strategy would be to convert the matrices back to the same size and then add them.

```
A <- sparseMatrix(8, 8, x = 1)
B <- sparseMatrix(c(1,3,5), c(3,6,3), x = c(1,4,1))
```

You can access the indices of matrix B with `summary(B)` and then just recreate the matrix with sparseMatrix(i,j,x,dims) like you would a normal subsetting operation in R:

```
> summary(B)
5 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix", with 3 entries 
  i j x
1 1 3 1
2 5 3 1
3 3 6 4

B <- sparseMatrix(i = summary(B)$i, j = summary(B)$j, x = summary(B)$x, dims = dim(A))
```

Then you can just add the matrices:

```
A = A + B
```

Comment: Good idea - works well, thanks a lot! I couldn't upvote you as I don't have enough points yet.