# Build a sparse table based on the information from two tables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics

I know there are some libraries that I can use in Python, but I am not sure with R..I wanna build a sparse table based on other tables in R based on the information from table1 and table2:

```py
#table1
content1 = {'gene_name':['gene1', 'gene2', 'gene3'], 'sample1':[1.0, 1.0, 2.0], 'sample2':[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 'sample3':[0.7, 0.6, 0.6]}
data1 = pd.DataFrame(content)
data2 = data.set_index('gene_name')

#table2
content2 = {'gene_name':['gene2', 'gene3', 'gene4'], 'sample4':[2.0, 4.0, 1.0], 'sample5':[0.8, 0.2, 0.3], 'sample6':[0.2, 0.1, 0.9]}
data2 = pd.DataFrame(content2)
data2 = data2.set_index('gene_name')
```

and I am interested in building a sparse dataframe like this:

```py
#final table
content {'gene_name':['gene1', 'gene2', 'gene3', 'gene4'], 
'sample1':[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, na], 
'sample2':[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, na], 
'sample3':[0.7, 0.6, 0.6, na], 
'sample4':[na, 2.0, 4.0, 1.0], 
'sample5':[na, 0.8, 0.2, 0.3],
'sample6':[na,0.2, 0.1, 0.9] }

the "gene_name" will turn into columns now, 
and samples will become rownames, with na filled the empty sapce
```

Any tip will be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How does your data1 and data2 look like? And what is the expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two dgCMatrix sparse matrices of different size in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827512/merge-two-dgcmatrix-sparse-matrices-of-different-size-in-r)